# Flutter App Crashes on x86 devices with java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, flutter, crash, android-x86

```
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/********************-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/********************-1/lib/x86, /data/app/********************-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:164)
at mc.f.g()
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>()
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>()
at io.flutter.embedding.android.d.G()
at io.flutter.embedding.android.d.p()
at io.flutter.embedding.android.h.K2()
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.p3()
at androidx.fragment.app.u.c()
at androidx.fragment.app.u.m()
at androidx.fragment.app.m.d0()
at androidx.fragment.app.m.d1()
at androidx.fragment.app.m.a0()
at androidx.fragment.app.m.S()
at androidx.fragment.app.m.y()
at androidx.fragment.app.h.c()
at androidx.fragment.app.e.onStart()
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/********************-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/********************-1/lib/x86, /data/app/********************-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary()
at mc.f$a.b()
at mc.f$a.call()
```

I have tried adding this `defaultConfig {ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a','x86_64'}` in my app level build.gradle file and also tried workarounds from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83596  but still the app crashes

Comment: `x86` (32 bit) is not `x86_64` (64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't use correct code.
Could you try this?

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a', 'x86_64' }
  }
}
```